# Returning RGB data for an arbitrary point on a scaled colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I have an xy scatter plot with points colored according to some third value z. In this case, x and y are arrays of pressure and volume data, and z is an array of temperature data.

```py
data = np.genfromtxt("watervolume.txt", delimiter="\t")
P=data[:,0]
V=data[:,1]
T=data[:,2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.scatter(P,V,c=T,cmap='jet')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
im.set_clim(400,4000)

ax.set_xlabel('P (GPa)')
ax.set_ylabel('V (cc/mol)')
ax.set_title('partial molar volume H2O')
fig.savefig('watervolume.pdf')
```

How can I find the RGB value for a given temperature value along the colorbar.

Comment: `im.to_rgba(temperature)`

Comment: This returns a strange output. The first three of four values returned for any temperature are less than 1.

Comment: Yes, all values are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Is there a way to get the values between 0-255?

Comment: multiply by 255?